# Python auto-instrumentation error when using K8s OpenTelemetry Operator

Tags: open-telemetry

When using a collector in deployment mode and auto-instrumenting python containers using the K8s operator we are receiving this error( java and nodejs are instrumenting properly):

```
manager {"level":"error","ts":"2023-08-01T19:00:00Z","msg":"failed to select an OpenTelemetry Instrumentation instance for this pod","namespace":"namespace","name":" │
│ ","error":"no OpenTelemetry Instrumentation instances available","stacktrace":"github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/pkg/instrumentation.(*instPodMutator).Mut │
│ ate\n\t/workspace/pkg/instrumentation/podmutator.go:87\ngithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/internal/webhookhandler.(*podSidecarInjector).Handle\n\t/workspa │
│ ce/internal/webhookhandler/webhookhandler.go:92\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/webhook/admission.(*Webhook).Handle\n\t/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0. │
│ 15.0/pkg/webhook/admission/webhook.go:169\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/webhook/admission.(*Webhook).ServeHTTP\n\t/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.15. │
│ 0/pkg/webhook/admission/http.go:98\ngithub.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp.InstrumentHandlerInFlight.func1\n\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/prometheus/client_g │
│ olang@v1.15.1/prometheus/promhttp/instrument_server.go:60\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2122\ngithub.com/prometheus/client_gola │
│ ng/prometheus/promhttp.InstrumentHandlerCounter.func1\n\t/go/pkg/mod/github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.15.1/prometheus/promhttp/instrument_server.go:147\nnet/http.H │
│ andlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2122\ngithub.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp.InstrumentHandlerDuration.func2\n\t/go/pkg/mod │
│ /github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.15.1/prometheus/promhttp/instrument_server.go:109\nnet/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2122\nn │
│ et/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2500\nnet/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2936\nnet/http.(*con │
│ n).serve\n\t/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1995"}
```

Pod Annotations that are in the pod spec:

```
instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/container-names: otel-getting-started                                                                                  instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/inject-python: opentelemetry-instrumentation/my-instrumentation
```

Instrumentation resource:

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: Instrumentation
metadata:
  annotations:
    instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/default-auto-instrumentation-apache-httpd-image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-apache-httpd:1.0.3
    instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/default-auto-instrumentation-dotnet-image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-dotnet:0.7.0
    instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/default-auto-instrumentation-go-image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-instrumentation/autoinstrumentation-go:v0.2.1-alpha
    instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/default-auto-instrumentation-java-image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-java:1.26.0
    instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/default-auto-instrumentation-nodejs-image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-nodejs:0.40.0
    instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/default-auto-instrumentation-python-image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-python:0.39b0
  creationTimestamp: "2023-05-12T18:56:38Z"
  generation: 25
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: opentelemetry-operator
  name: my-instrumentation
  namespace: opentelemetry-instrumentation
spec:
  apacheHttpd:
    configPath: /usr/local/apache2/conf
    image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-apache-httpd:1.0.3
    version: "2.4"
  dotnet:
    env:
    - name: OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER
      value: none
    - name: OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER
      value: none
    - name: OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER
      value: otlp
    image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-dotnet:0.7.0
  exporter: {}
  java:
    env:
    - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT
      value: http://deployment-collector.opentelemetry.svc.cluster.local:4317
    - name: OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER
      value: none
    - name: OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER
      value: none
    - name: OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER
      value: otlp
    image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-java:1.26.0
  nodejs:
    env:
    - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT
      value: http://deployment-collector.opentelemetry.svc.cluster.local:4317
    - name: OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER
      value: none
    - name: OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER
      value: none
    - name: OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER
      value: otlp
    image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-nodejs:0.40.0
  propagators:
  - tracecontext
  - baggage
  - b3multi
  - b3
  python:
    env:
    - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT
      value: http://deployment-collector.opentelemetry.svc.cluster.local:4318
    - name: OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER
      value: none
    - name: OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER
      value: none
    - name: OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER
      value: otlp
    image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-python:0.39b0
  resource: {}
  sampler: {}
```

Adding more details to get past the details linting that is going on and saying that I'm posting too much code but that's the only way to format most of what I'm trying to post.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this:

The error was a mistake on my part. I had added the inject annotation to the namespace for java and forgot to remove that annotation which created a conflict between the namespace annotation and the pod annotation. Moral of the story is cleanup after testing.